# User Role based routes in Symfony

Tags: symfony, routes, middleware, acl, user-roles

I've got five types of **roles** in my Symfony project.

I want to create restrictions for each role, so that they will have access to specific routes. They will not be able to access others paths. I want to do this in an efficient way like **Laravel** uses **middleware** in the routes for access. Is there any way like this in **Symfony**?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html

Answer (score -1):

You could do that in different ways, and it depends on your Symfony version.

In the older Symfony versions, the most common way to restrict access to certain routes is adding into `config/packages/security.yaml` some parameters such as:

```
 access_control:
    - { path: '^/agent', roles: ROLE_AGENT }
    - { path: '^/profile', roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: '^/admin', roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: '^/admin/statistics', roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

Also, it's good practice to define the role hierarchy into the same file `config/packages/security.yaml` :

```
`role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN`
```

Hence, the users with a SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE will have access to routes restricted to ROLE_ADMIN.

However, my recommendation is if you've several parts to restrict define the general access roles into the `config/packages/security.yaml` file such as and define a role hierarchy as I said before:

```
 access_control:
    - { path: '^/admin', roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: '^/profile', roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Then restrict the other routes using annotations thanks to [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html), for example:

```
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;

 /**
  * Require ROLE_ADMIN_SYSTEMS for *every* controller method in         this class.
  *
  * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN_SYSTEMS")
  */

   public function YourFunction() { }
```

For more information look into official Symfony Docs that are very clear. [Symfony Security official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html)

I hope this could help you, if you've any other doubts just tell me,

Kind regards.

Comment: So the routes which will be start with /admin, only admin will have access to those? Like if the route is admin/users then only Admin will be able to check the user list?

Comment: Yes, Farhan every sub-route that starts by  /admin. Eg. /admin/users, /admin/analytics, etc. Those routes will be accessible for users with admin_role.
Please if you can upvote my answer, thanks!